# How to convert a string to date and extract values in Access query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I'm using Access DB 2007 - 2010; I've tried to import many CSV files but the timestamp column keeps failing to import correctly.

So I linked all of the CSV's to an Access DB and I'm trying to query all of the tables.

I'm trying to extract the year and day of the year from the time stamp (which is currently a string)

I'm trying to combine the `Format` with `datepart` functions and it keeps failing. (it just says error in the table)

The `format` function by itself works but I can't combine it with anything.

I'm basically trying to do this:

```
select datepart("y", Format(gmt, "dd-mmm-yyyy hh:nn:ss")) as DOY from Table1;
```

but it fails. I've also tried `CDate` and `DateValue` in different combinations but it all fails.

Does anyone know how to get this to work?

**UPDATE**

The `format` function isn't doing anything. The text remains the same no matter how I try to format it.

Here's a datetime sample: 05-Dec-2008 13:40:01.955

Comment: @HansUp: It fails; I added the date sample

Comment: @HansUp: OMG! That worked! Thank you so much! Please add that as a solution so I can upvote that!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Access can't cope with the milliseconds in your date strings.

Use `Left()` to exclude them and feed the resulting substring to `CDate()`.

```sql
SELECT CDate(Left(gmt, 20)) AS date_from_string
FROM Table1;
```

Once you have a valid Date/Time value, you can use `Year(<Date/Time value>)` or `DatePart("yyyy", <Date/Time value>)` to extract the year.  And  `DatePart("y", <Date/Time value>)` will give you the day of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Just solve this issue, here is my code for your reference:

```
update tablename
set date=cdate(format(left(gmt,4)&"-"&right(gmt,2),"yyyy-mm"))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: That is overly convoluted, less optimal than the accepted answer.